# Execution failed for task ":app:checkDebugAarMetadata"

Tags: flutter

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.material:material:.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material//material-.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/material/material//material-.pom
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/android/material/material//material-.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 6s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
  Exited

I am getting this error while running my app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.